# Reference error while compiling C file in VS2010 command-prompt

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010

I have VS 2010 installed on my system and i was trying to compile a simple hello.c in VS command prompt. The compilation gave an error.

`Fatal Error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h' no such file, folder exist`

Why this error is coming ?? Does VS2010 not include reference files/assemblies for C.

Comment: ya...sorry for the typing mistake, will make an edit

Comment: You might need to compile the file as C, by default it assumes C++. You can use /TC on the command line.

Comment: @tinman: by default it will compile it as C if the filename extension is `.c`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

VS 2010 certainly does contain the standard headers.  You should check that your command prompt environment is set up correctly.  There should be an environment variable named `INCLUDE` that has a directory similar to the cfollowing (among other directories) in it:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\INCLUDE
```

that directory (the name may vary slightly, for example depending on if your machine is a 64-bit OS of not) should include `stdio.h`

If you don't have such a directory in your environment, then you're not setting up the environment correctly.  You should use on of the "Visual Studio Command Prompt" shortcuts that VS installs, or simply run

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat
```

With the appropriate parameter to get the environment you want (`x86` or `amd64` for example).

If the `INCLUDE` environment variable does have an entry like that, but the `stdio.h` file doesn't exist, then you might need to reinstall VS.

Comment: +1 for using the default "Visual Studio Command Prompt" shortcut - that's definitely the easiest way to go.

Comment: @Pankaj: what does the `INCLUDE` variable look like? Do the directories in it look like they have what should be in them (specifically, is `stdio.h` missing from `VC\INCLUDE`)?

Comment: This directory `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC` doesn't have any folder named `INCLUDE`. Can this be the reason ??

Comment: That sure can be the reason - that's where VS puts the library headers.  I think that somehow they got deleted or moved elsewhere by mistake on your machine. You might want to search your disk to see if the directory got moved en masse somewhere (it can be easy to drag-n-drop a directory by accident in Explorer). If that's the case, just move it back. You might want to consider reinstalling VS instead in case things are more messed up than that.

Comment: Thanks Michael. I didn't find the INCLUDE directory. But will re-install the software tomorrow to see if my version of VS2010 Professional installes this directory or not

Comment: After a fresh install of VS 2012, my `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include` directory was pretty empty, with no `stdio.h` to be seen. However, after installing the SP4 update, things are fixed! (no need to reinstall the entire stack in my case)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem as the OP the VC folder was missing most of the files.  I tried both repairing and uninstalling/reinstalling VS 2010 but neither worked.

What worked for me was installing the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86).[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555)

Answer (score 0):

There are so many versions of so much Windows system code that it's easy for a path to become invalid.

In my case:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Include
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib
```

needed to be changed to::

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include
```

and

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib
```

i.e. `v7.1A -> v7.0A` (don't ask why, it just part of the everyday, tiresome task of dealing with Microsoft!).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The file stdio.h did not exist in folder include. I removed VS 2010 using the Control Panel then reinstalled, but this didn't solve the problem.

I then used the VS 2010 installation CD to remove all of VS 2010, and manually removed anything leftover by Control Panel. I then installed VS 2010 professional again. The problem was solved.